# Phonegap: External links not opening in Safari on iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, window.open, inappbrowser

When trying to open external urls on iOS 9 with phonegap using 
`window.open("www.google.com", '_system')` method it opens the link inside the app but it is supposed to open it in Safari.On iOS 8 the links were opened in Safari just fine.

Comment: can you tell the cordova ios version, plugin version and xcode version? are you sure you could open urls without http before?

Comment: I have Phonegap(and Cordova) version 5.3.1, inAppBrowser version 1.0.1(latest from github) and xcode 7. The problem isnt that I can't open urls, it is that the urls are opened inside app but they are supposed to open in Safari.

Comment: just created a new project, added inAppBrowser from github, added 
       `window.open("http://www.google.com", '_system');` on the device ready and run on ios 9, it's working fine (it opens in safari)

Comment: @jcesarmobile did you try that in the simulator or on an actual device? For whatever reason it works for me in the simulator but not on a device.

Comment: iPhone 6 with iOS 9 GM and the final iOS 9

Comment: Updating cordova using `npm update -g cordova` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Following is what worked for me.
1. update cordova CLI

```
sudo npm upgate -g cordova
```

2. update platforms

   cordova platform update ios
3. Create a new project.
4. replace the content of www folder and config.xml file with your older one.
5. add ios platform and build.

Please note: you might get some issues on iOS9, for instance some conflicting code, which you might need to google and fix.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that the InAppBrowser Plugin is installed?

```
cordova plugin list
```

You need that plugin to get window.open() to work properply.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I have the inappbrowser plugin installed.

Comment: Yes the inAppBrowser plugin is installed and works fine on every other platform.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that after updating PhoneGap, the plugins won't load anymore for iOS when building in OS X. When i built it in Windows (using older phonegap-ios 3.8.0, NOT 3.9+), it loaded the plugins properly. So the problem is not related to iOS 9, but is related to PhoneGap.